# Stellar.toml on the test network?

Tags: testnet

Is setting the home domain for an asset supposed to work on the Stellar test network?

I issued a test token, set the home domain for the issuing account, and made sure the stellar.toml was accessible (set the CORS header, etc).  However, when I look at my asset on https://stellar.expert/explorer/testnet/asset/KRBO-GAE23RKNKC3YCQGKBAZ2GLOVDC6TJXMKMRMQ7IZDYBAUEXF3PTCFO53B it shows "related domain not found".

Has anyone done this successfully on the test network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks ok for me. Try to ping the domain `staging.kurbo.com` from your local computer, there's a chance that your browser/os cached the DNS response.

[image: verified domain screnshot]